# Treeview get selected nodes third childnode

Tags: vb.net

My treeview looks like this:

- ParentNode

  - Childnode1
  - Childnode2
  - Childnode3 < I want to get the text of this node when you click on the parentnode
  - Childnode4
  - Childnode5

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as using the indexer property of the `Nodes` collection of your node, like this:

```
YourNode.Nodes(2).Text
```

If you have handled `NodeMouseClick` event of your TreeView, the second parameter `e as  TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs` can be used like this:

```
Public Sub YourTreeView_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs)
    If YourTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count > 2 Then
        MsgBox(YourTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes(2).Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("No 3rd node is available.")
End Sub
```

Comment: I have more than one parent node with 5 childnodes in them, can't you do like TreeView1.SelectedNode(2).Text or something? Because when I run this code i get a source not avalible error

Comment: And if you didn't get what I was trying to do, I'm trying to get the text of the 3rd childnode of the selected parent.

Comment: Of course you can use `YourTreeView.SelectedNode` in the very same way as I have used `e.Node` above. The point is that after a node is clicked, `e.Node` will be same as `YourTreeView.SelectedNode`. The only diff is that you can use `YourTreeView.SelectedNode` anywhere in the form code, whereas `e.Node` works only inside this event-handler.

Comment: So to get the third childnode of a selected parentnode I can do what exactly? Don't really get what you're saying

Comment: `YourTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes(2)`

Comment: Cannot be converted to string, Nodes(2).text doesn't work either

Comment: I still don't get how I'm supposed to do this, I'm trying to get the text of the 3rd childnode in a selected parent node

Comment: Add your code to the question. I'll see what you're doing wrong. This really isn't supposed to be all that difficult.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63511/discussion-between-elementaltree-and-dotnet).

Comment: @ElementalTree: Updated code according to our discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Got what I was looking for thanks to @dotNET

```
Private Sub TreeView1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    If TreeView1.SelectedNode IsNot Nothing AndAlso TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Count > 2 Then
        Link = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes(2).Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks